# Rails: Expire fragment that has key generated with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

If I am generating a cache block like so:

```
<% cache ['v1', current_user, 'info'] do %>
  Info HEre
<% end %>
```

How do I go about expiring the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write this line of code in all actions where you edit this fragment:

```
expire_fragment(['v1', current_user, 'info'])
```